# Mootools is not defined

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools, firebug

MooTools.More={version:"1.2.4.2",build:"bd5a93c0913cce25917c48cbdacde568e15e02ef"};(function(){var a={language:"en-US",languages:{"en-US":{}},cascades:["en-US"]};

-->mootools is not defined in firebug.

I am making a contact Us formchecker.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools/mootols-1.js">     </script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js"></script> 


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/formcheck/lang/en.js"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/formcheck/formcheck.js"> </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/formcheck/theme/blue/formcheck.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new FormCheck('myform');
});
```

```
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try fixing the spelling of "mootols" in the first line.

Comment: This is probably the answer. If the error persists, refresh the page, or view the source to make sure that the page is updating. Hold shift when reloading to do a forced reload (works in Firefox and Chrome to my knowledge).

Answer (score 2):

If this is your mootools core:

```
js/mootools/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js
```

Then what is this?

```
js/mootools/mootools-1.js
```

Could it be mootools more? You need to load the core first.

Answer (score 2):

MooTools-More code depends on MooTools-Core code to be loaded first.

Make sure that MooTools-Core is loaded before MooTools-More.